# How can I use the filter option to only view names of agents that are in particular groups?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

On the top rows are some groups that each agent is assigned. What I want is to use some kind of tool or formula that can display columns of those agents that have the desired groups. For example, if I want to look for agents that are in the A-team group, I want it to display only the data of Agent B, Agent C and Agent D. Also if it can exclude the ones that are either OFF or on PTO.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  Please include a mockup of what the successful approach would produce.

Answer (score 0):

The **Data > Create a filter** feature only filters by rows and not by columns.

You may want to use a `filter()` formula to show in a separate table the rows and columns that match your criteria.

To get started, you can filter columns so that only the A-Team shows like this:

`=filter(F11:J, len(F8:J8))`

Put the formula in row `11` in a free area of the sheet.

To only show rows that are on a particular date, wrap the formula in another `filter()`. To leave out agents that are OFF or PTO on that date, wrap the formula in yet another `filter()`.